# How to choose between little endian or big endian for the processor settings?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, compiler

We have just selected a new processor for our application, and one of the project options available to me is to select the Endian mode: Little endian or Big endian (under Big endian two more choices, BE32 and BE8)

Can you please tell me what factors I should consider to make this choice?

I was under the impression that a processor is either Little endian based or Big Endian. Does this mean that based on the option selected, the compiler would fix the endianess to suit the processor, if required?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which processor?

Comment: We are using an ARM Cortex M series chip from ST and using an IAR compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's kind of an overdone argument these days - either works well,  if you're writing code that actually cares and you want it to be portable you're going to code any dependencies out anyway

so why might you choose?

Big Endian: almost all network protocols are BE - this is probably the main reason to choose these days

Little Endian: there are a few data tricks (like passing an int and treating it as a char) that are available - but none of them are portable so best avoided

Comment: One more thing to add: If you're say developing an operating system, or any code which will run on both your ARM processor and some other type of processor(such as x86), almost all modern processors now use little endian. Usually, it's nothing to worry about. But when doing very many bitwise operations, even subtle "simple" things can break.

Comment: As mentioned above the world is little endian, the processor market embedded and desktop are owned by little endian and they network just fine.  Doing your system engineering solves all of those problems anyway.  As far as an ARM or any platform you are best by going with native mode, in this case little endian.  The tools will work better, operating systems, etc.  With arm you are either BE8 or BE32 they dont have both on the same core.  The cortex-m's are BE8, which is that much more complicated and risky, go little endian with an ARM, make your life easier.

Answer (score 5):

Incidentally, I know of an argument that historically favored little-endian format: in a number of CPUs, most notably the 6502, code could run faster using little-endian format than would have been possible with big-endian.  Consider, for example, an instruction:

```
$1234:  LDA ($8A),Y ; Load byte from Y register plus the value stored in $008B-$008A
Assume $008B-$008A hold $5432, and Y holds $10
```

The execution sequence is:

```
$1234 read $B1 - Fetch opcode
$1235 read $8A - Fetch operand
$008A read $32 - Fetch LSB of target while adding $01 to $8A
$008B read $54 - Fetch MSB of target while adding $32 to $10
$5442 read $XX - Fetch byte from target
```

The MSB and LSB of any address to be read or written must be either based on a computation done in the last cycle with values already in the CPU, or else must be the last fetched value verbatum.  The third cycle can read the first byte of the target address (i.e. $8A) without delay; if the processor wanted to read the second byte first, it would have to waste a cycle computing the address.  The fourth cycle can compute the LSB of the target address while fetching the MSB; if there's no carry out of the LSB, the LSB (computed) and MSB (fetched from memory) will be ready simultaneously.  If the 6502 were big-endian, it would be necessary to waste a cycle on every indexed access (instead of only losing a cycle when indexing crosses a 256-byte boundary).

I'm unaware of any processing advantage to big-endian format beyond the fact that it was arbitrarily chosen as the "standard" network byte order.

Comment: I know it is a old answer, but I always presume BE in networking is chosen, so that a router can forward packets for different networks, without the need to read the full address. IPv6 is 128 bits, so this can be done with only 64 msb, and last 64 are needed only for the last networking devices at the packet destination. Can someone please, confirm or deny my presumption?

Comment: @zzz: It's an interesting theory, but I'm not sure how many routers or switches will attempt to start forwarding a packet based upon a partial address before validating the remainder.  A bigger issue is that for some kinds of hardware operation (e.g. CRC) can be performed more easily on serial data if the order of bits in a byte matches the order of bytes in a word, whether both are big-endian or little-endian.  Others require one ordering or the other, and would have to reverse bits in a byte if it didn't match what was otherwise required.  For example...

Comment: ...one could fairly easily build a fast long-multiplication accelerator peripheral for LSB-first serial data which, after receiving one multiplicand, could then accept a second multiplicand of arbitrary length and clock each bit of result as the corresponding bit of the the second multiplicand was clocked in.

Answer (score 3):

The time that engineers spend thinking about endianness is not free in a commercial project. On an ARM processor, little endian is the path of least resistance. Unless you have an overriding justification, definitely choose little endian, as this is ARM's traditional endianness.

Answer (score 2):

What processor is it? It is generally the case that there is a preferred mode that everyone uses. For instance, the Microchip C32 compiler for the MIPS-based PIC32 uses little-endian format.

Comment: In fact, I'm not aware of any processor where indianness is selectable.

Comment: Actually, quite a few are selectable http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Bi-endian_hardware

Comment: That's actually quite cool!

Comment: @drxzcl: On processors that don't support unaligned access, the most expensive part of the hardware to make endian-ness selectable would be the latch to select the mode.  Otherwise, if the hardware has two signals that are 00 for word accesses, 01 for half-word, and 11 for byte, and a signal that's 0 for one endianness and 1 for the other, all that's required to make endian-ness selectable would be two AND gates and two XOR gates.

Comment: @drxzcl: To switch between the two forms of endianness, simply flip the bottom 2 bits of byte addresses, or the second-to-bottom bit of half-word addresses.  Nothing else in the system needs to care about endianness.

Answer (score 0):

It only matters if you're interfacing with the outside world i.e. if data has to be passed out from the processor or read into the processor.

If you are not careful, you end up with flipped-order bytes. As others have mentioned, networks use big-endian format. So, that is something to consider. Another possible consideration is when you have a multi-processor setup and they need to share data.

Also, some processor [architectures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Bi-endian_hardware) can switch endianness in software.